# Not able to pass an authguard after login - Angular

Tags: angular, logging, token

After I log in I can see the current user value on the console, but I'm not getting redirected to the home page, that uses an authguard service; only if I refresh the page and input the credentials again... If I redirect to a page without guard, or if I lose the home page guard, the log in is succesfull for the first time. Also, in the navbar, the name of the current user doesn't disapear after I log out, only if I refresh it ...Can someone help me understand this behavior and solve the issue?

The AuthService

```
private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  login(credentials: any) {
    return this.http.post('/users/authenticate', credentials)
      .pipe(map(user => {
        if (user)
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        return user;
      }))
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
  }
```

The login ts:

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.invalid)
      return;
    let credentials = {
      userName: this.userName.value,
      password: this.password.value
    }
    this.authService.login(credentials).subscribe(data => {
      let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl');
      this.router.navigate(['/home'||returnUrl  ]);
      console.log(data);
    },(error:any)=>{
      console.log(error)
      this.errorMessage=true;
    })
  }
```

This module routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'home', component: HomeComponent ,  canActivate:[AuthGuardService] },
  {path:'movieDetail/:title', component:DetailComponent},
  {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'}

];
```

The guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.authService.currentUserValue) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Notice that I use a fakebackend that returns a fake jwt token but i don't think it has to do with anything...

Comment: is there anyone out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the BehaviorSubject `currentUserSubject` is not being emitted after login.
Please check what `this.authService.currentUserValue` return when the route is `/home`.
If its `null` or `undefined` please set it. Also when you reload, it does not clear the local storage so the constructor of you service set the BehaviorSubject.

Instead of this i would recommend you to modify your `auth.guard.ts`.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
  return true;
} else {
  this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
  return false;
}
```

}